# Number of elements in a ring with identity s.t. $x^2 = 1_R$ for all $0_R \neq x\in R$?

Tags: ring-theory

I'm not sure how to go about finding the solution to this question.

> Let R be a ring with identity such that $x^2 = 1_R$ for all $0_R \neq x\in R$. How many elements are in $R$?

I've just been playing around with squaring elements, like $$(x+1_R)^2 = x^2+2.x+1_R =2.x+2.1_R = 1_R.$$

But I'm not sure where to go with this. Any help?

Comment: Either $1_R+1_R=0$ or $(1_R+1_R)^2=1_R$ so $3\cdot 1_R=0$.

Answer (score 11):

One possibility, of course, is $R=\{0\}$. Assume $1_R\neq 0$.

$R$ has no zero divisors: if $xy=0$ and $x\neq 0$, then $y = 1_Ry = xxy = x(0)=0$.

$R$ is commutative: if $x$ and $y$ are nonzero, then so is $xy$ by the above; hence $(xy)^2 = x^2y^2$; canceling from $xyxy=xxyy$ we get $yx=xy$.

(Of course, the ring satisfies $x^3=x$ for all $x$, so by a famous theorem of Jacobson, the ring is necessarily commutative; but we don't need to call in that heavy cannon to the fray).

Since every nonzero element is invertible, $R$ is a field. Since $x^2-1_R$ has $|R-\{0\}|$ solutions, we have $|R-\{0\}|\leq 2$, so $|R|\leq 3$.

If $1_R+1_R=0$, then $R$ is of characteristic $2$, so $R\cong \mathbb{F}_2$ and $|R|=2$. And, indeed, in this case the hypothesis holds.

If $1_R+1_R\neq 0$, then we get $4\cdot 1_R = 1_R$, hence $3\cdot 1_R=0$, so $R$ is of characteristic $3$, and therefore $R\cong\mathbb{F}_3$ and $|R|=3$. Again, the hypothesis holds for this ring.

In summary, $R$ has either $1$, $2$, or $3$ elements, and is either the trivial ring, $\mathbb{F}_2$, or $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, but why does $x^3=x$ imply that $R$ is commutative?

Comment: @098765: It is a [common exercise](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/sci.math/3z7C7-OcHGo/EB81MfdKiJsJ) in Ring Theory, and also a consequence of a famous Theorem of Jacobson, which states that a ring for which there exists $n\gt 0$ such that $x^n=x$ for all $x$ is always commutative. But I gave a simpler derivation that does not call upon such heavy artillery in an edit.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin am pleased you revised your answer, because the proof that $x^3 = x$ implies R is commutative isn't trivial, and is probably beyond the stage at which the asker of this question is at.

Comment: Does your proof actually depend on commutativity? (mine does not). If not, then you can omit the proof of comutativity, since it's a trivial consequence of the final result.

Comment: @Bill: I use commutativity only to conclude that I have a field rather than a simply division ring; I believe it is equivalent to your "$x^{-1}=x\Rightarrow R$ field".

Answer (score 2):

$\rm R=0\:$ works. Else $\rm\ x\ne 0$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm x^2 =1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm x^{-1} = x $ $\Rightarrow$ $\rm R$ field, so $\rm\: x\ne 0\!\iff\!\! (x-1)(x+1) = 0$ $\iff$ $\rm x=\pm 1.\:$ But $\rm\: R\backslash0 = \{\pm1\}$ $\!\iff\!$ $\rm R\:\! \cong\:\! \mathbb Z/2\:$ or $\:\mathbb Z/3$.

More generally, the finite fields $\:\rm\mathbb F_p,\: \mathbb F_q,\ p,q\:$ prime, are axiomatized by the ring axioms plus
$$\rm x^n =\: x,\quad n\: =\: 1 + lcm(p\!-\!1,q\!-\!1)$$
$$\rm q\:(x^p-x)\: =\: 0\: =\: p\:(x^q-x)$$
$$\rm pq\: =\: 0$$

Thus any identity true in both of these fields has a purely equational proof from the above axioms. This theorem extends similarly to any finite set of finite fields, for example see  Stanley Burris and John Lawrence, [Term rewrite rules for finite fields (1991).](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.85.9115) This result is very closely related to Jacobson's model-theoretic proof of commutativity of rings satisfying the identity $\rm\: x^{n_x} =\: x$.